# Lazy loading sub modules of a sub module to the app

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I am writing an angular app, the app itself lazily loads home.module to '' path based on some decisions or other modules would be loaded

When home.module loads it loads with a nav bar(a seperate component) with 4 menu options. Now, when i click on any of the items, i should go to respective module. But angular is complaining that it couldnt match any routes.

here are snippets from my files

app-routing.ts

```
import { HomeGuardService } from './route-guard/home-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [ 
    { 
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule),
    canActivate: [HomeGuardService] }, 
    // other routes go here
 }]; 
 @NgModule({ imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], exports: [RouterModule] }) 
 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home-routing.ts

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component'; 


const routes: Routes = [ { 
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    component: HomeComponent, 
    children: [ 
        { 
            path: 'search', 
            pathMatch: 'full', 
            loadChildren: () => import('./search/search.module').then(mod => mod.SearchModule) 
        }, 
        { 
            path: '/settings', 
            pathMatch: 'full', 
            loadChildren: () => import('./settings/settings.module').then(mod => mod.SettingsModule) 
        }] 
    } ] 
    @NgModule({ imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ], exports: [ RouterModule ] }) 
    export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

search-routing.module.ts

```
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component'; 

const routes: Routes = [ { path: '', component: SearchComponent } ]; 
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)], 
    exports: [RouterModule] 
}) 
export class SearchRoutingModule { }
```

home-component.html

```
<div>
    <div class="header">
        <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- main app content : routing content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <app-nav-menu (sendMenuSelection)="changeRoute($event)"></app-nav-menu>
    </div>
</div>
```

home-component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 

    constructor( private router: Router ) { }

    private changeRoute(menuSelection) { t
    this.router.navigate([menuSelection]); 
    }
}
```

now, nav-menu component just has 4 clickable icons that emit event to home component as you can see above. In the component.ts, am trying to use router.navigate to navigate to respective path.

I want the route to load as such on the root path - /search, /settings etc.

Am relatively new to angular and would appreciate any help on getting around this error that i see.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using code to navigate, you could just put `[routerLink]="['/settings']"` in your app-nav-menu component and remove the changeRoute method. Like this: `<a [routerLink]="['/settings']">Settings</a>`. Also could you try removing the `pathMatch: 'full'` and see if that changes anything as well as removing the / in front of settings in your routing, those options are not required in your routing for the things you want to accomplish I think, can you try these things and see if you still have the error?

Comment: i did try removing the pathMatch, that wouldnt help. Also, i saw that the implementation for routerLink directive is calling router.navigate, so can you please let me know why adding the directive is a better idea ?

Comment: In my opinion it makes it makes everything look a bit cleaner, no need to reinvent the wheel. Is your SearchRoutingModule imported in your SearchModule?

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I fixed this myself. Removing pathMatch:full on this path in app.routing-module.ts fixed it for me